# iOS - NSPredicate One-to-Many Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, one-to-many, nspredicate

I have two entities: Dictionary and DictionaryItems

A 'Dictionary' has a one to many relationship called 'terms' to the 'DictionaryItems' Entity

i.e. Dictionary = English
     DictionaryItems = Cabbage, Babble, Green, Bus

I have two tables, the first shows a list of my Dictionary objects i.e.:

English
Spanish
Klingon

After touching one of those, it pushes on a new table that should show all of the items contained in that dictionary.

However my NSPredicate seems to be the problem as nothing is showing in that 2nd Table.

I've used a Mac app that interrogates the SQL database backend and I can confirm all the entries are there, and the relationship seems to be wired up correctly... however nothing is returned and it seems to be the NSPredicate's fault.

This is what I have:

```
NSEntityDescription * entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"DictionaryItems" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dictionary == %@", self.myDictionaryManagedObject];

[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

Where 'self.myDictionaryObject' is a property containing the 'Dictionary' Managed Object chosen from the first table. This object is valid and correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the fix:

```
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY SELF.dictionary = %@", self.myDictionaryObject];
```

Knew it was the predicate!!

Answer (score 0):

In your question you say that those entities are `DictionaryTerms`.  However, you are creating an `NSEntityDescription` with the name `DictionaryItems`.

Comment: With that correction, the code you've posted looks ok to me.  Maybe the problem isn't with your predicate.  Can you post more code? Code from the view controller handles your '2nd Table', as well how you get data to that view controller might be helpful.

Comment: There's no point. I know that the rest of the vc and table and nsfetchrequest  is working because if I change the entity to the parent entity and remove the predicate it populates the table correctly with the parent Dictionary objects

Comment: No problem...I'm sure someone else can answer your question based only on the information you've given.

Comment: That sounds faintly sarcastic to me... right? I'm not being flippant - but I can post the entire class, or host the entire project somewhere, but surely the problem is specific enough that a Core Data whizz will be able to explain where I'm going wrong?